# Python parallel process to write s3 file

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, multiprocessing

I have a queue in which i have > 10k of rows and i am using parallel processing to write to file on s3 but no luck. Any idea how can that be archived?

I am already using `smart_open` package to open the file and to write.

```
with smart_open.smart_open(key, 'w') as fout:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(fout)
    csvwriter.writerow(inrow)
```

Above code in written inside a function , which i am running by creating multiple threads. inrow is the list of elements that is present in the queue(list of queue).

Comment: Can you share your code? What errors are you facing? That could help to have a straight answer

Comment: Please find my code in the description of the post.

Comment: My question is, Is there a way to write to a file on object store(s3) via python multiprocessing/multithreading? . Can we create some s3 stream to write to the file continuously with multiple thread?